# Unexpected output from directional keypress in MacOS

Tags: keyboard, terminal, python, ncurses

I'm using MacOS 10.14.3 and the Python 3.7 curses module to print the values returned when I press the up or down directional keys:

```
import curses

def main(stdscr):
    win = curses.newwin(24, 80, 0, 0)
    while True:
        ch = win.getch()
        win.addstr(str(ch) + '\n')

curses.wrapper(main)
```

When I press up, this prints:

```
27
91
65
```

When I press down, it prints:

```
27
91
66
```

From the docs, [getch should](https://docs.python.org/3/library/curses.html#curses.window.getch) be returning 258 (curses.KEY_UP) or 259 (curses.KEY_DOWN), respectively. Any idea what could be causing this behavior? Is my terminal misconfigured?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`keypad`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/curses.html#curses.window.keypad) function, e.g.,

```
win.keypad(1);
```

before the loop (and after `newwin`).